# Animate NSImageView translation

Tags: swift, animation, core-animation, appkit

I'm trying to animate an NSImageView so it slides down a few points and fades-in while doing so.
After searching around a few hours I've only managed to get the alpha value to animate.
Translating the view works, but it's not animated and I can't figure out why.

```swift
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var logo: NSImageView!
    @IBAction func doAnimation(_ sender: Any) {

        animateLogo()

    }

    private func animateLogo() {
        let top = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 30, 0)
        logo.wantsLayer = true

        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) in
            Swift.print("Running animation")
            context.duration = 5
            logo.animator().alphaValue = 0

            logo.layer?.transform = top
        }, completionHandler: {
            Swift.print("Finished animation")
        })
    }

}
```

Another approach I've tried in translating the NSView is

```swift
logo.animator().translateOrigin(to: new_origin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using auto layout you can add an `outlet` to one of your constraints and change the `constant` value through the `animator`.

### Example

Here I have a view with a label and a button

[image: My view]

The label has two constraints.

- It is centred horizontally in the view
- It has a distance of 80 to the bottom of the view

I can now find the "distance to bottom" outlet in the Document Outline

[image: this guy]

And ctrl drag it to my corresponding `NSViewController` where I create an `outlet` for it.

```
@IBOutlet weak var distanceToBottom: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

I can verify that the `outlet` is set by looking at the Connections Inspector in the right side of the screen

[image]

Last step is to animate the view. Here I'm just using an `IBAction` on a `NSButton` like so:

```
@IBAction func animate(_ sender: NSButton) {
    distanceToBottom.animator().constant = 5
}
```

If I run that my label animates nicely to its new position 5 pixels from the bottom.

[image: final result]

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you! I've manage to animate my image using it's top constraint.

Comment: @JasonSuave you're welcome, glad you got it working. Once you find out that you can add outlets to constraints...it just makes animations and autolayout easier right? :)